# query on slds-has-error doesn't fetch nodes

Tags: slds

`let errs = this.template.querySelectorAll("slds-has-error");` returns a proxy. But I'm unable to get fields which have an error.
If I execute `errs.item.length` I'm getting 1 and running `errs.item[0]` I'm getting undefined.

My form contains 3 required fields which I haven't filled in.
In fact, I'm trying to find a workaround for this [pick list problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302869/lightning-record-edit-form-not-taking-the-focus-to-the-required-field)

Thanks

Comment: Can you write it as let err  = ... [ this.template.querySelectorAll("slds-has-error")] ; then share results

Comment: I guess you wanted to write let err = [...this.template.querySelectorAll("slds-has-error")] ;  In that case I got Array [] length: 0

Comment: By using $() in the console, I can select an element of the dom. But when using document.getElementById I get null. $('#combobox-button-1060') returns my button, document.getElementById('#combobox-button-1060') returns null